# Not able to Resolve NavigationContext in WPF xaml page have referenced System.Windows.Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF application and passing data from one page to another using navigation service but when I am trying to access navigation context to resolve query string, it not getting resolved I have already referenced System.Windows.Navigation

Sending IP from Home Page to Page1

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml? 
   IP="+txtIP.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

On Page1 Loaded event not able to resolve Navigation Context

```
 private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
            string val;
            if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("IP", out val))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(val, "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationContext` is a Silverlight type. If you add a reference to `System.Web`, you could use the `HttpUtility` to extract the parameters from the `NavigationService`'s `CurrentSource` property:

```
private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string uri = this.NavigationService.CurrentSource.ToString();
    string querystring = uri.ToString().Substring(uri.IndexOf('?'));
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);

    string val = parameters["IP"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(val, "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```